# Use of 「～ておりますしょうか。 」

Tags: grammar

I came across this construct that I'm not familiar with:

> 「。。。推移しておりますしょうか。」

What is the use of the ending　「～おりますしょうか。」 
I assumed it to be a shortening of 「～おりますでしょうか」 seeing as the meaning seems to be the same. Is this correct?

Comment: 0 hits in [BCCWJ](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/search_form) for 「ますしょうか」

Comment: Did you read it here? http://chikuden-setsuden.com/case-study/data/17.html

Comment: @blutorange Nope, company emails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this was a typo. 「しておりますしょうか」 itself is neither grammatical nor commonly accepted. Your assumption that it was meant to mean 「しておりますでしょうか」 is perfectly rigid.

Comment: It seems to be a very common spelling mistake as ”おりますしょうか” gets 4,350 hits on Google. I figured formal writing was better proof-read, but it seems to not be the case.

Comment: @Norbles But 4,350 is just an estimate, not a result count.  If you click through to the second page, you'll see that there are [only 14 results on Google](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E3%81%8A%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%22&start=10), two of which are for your question.

Comment: Ha! The estimates have generally been close. I've never seen one that bad. I'll have to double check before quoting Google again.